# ¿Por que no recibo el mismo tamaño de array en mi función?

Tags: c++

quiero pasar el tamaño de mi array a mi función , pero no logro que sea el mismo tamaño, se que es el tamaño de bytes, pero no puedo. Ayuda por favor.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void a(string as[]) {
    int tam = sizeof(as);
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        cout << as[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << tam;
}
int main() {
    string* as;
    as = new string[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        getline(cin, as[i]);
    }
    a(as);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si tan sólo quieres pasar a tu función el tamaño de tu array, ¿por qué no pasas como parámetro de tu función el tamaño directamente como `sizeof(as)`?

Answer (score 1):

Esto no hace lo que crees:

```
int tam = sizeof(as);
```

En este caso, `sizeof` está midiendo el tamaño de `as` cuyo tipo es `string []`; es decir `as` es un puntero y te dará el tamaño del puntero.

Tu no quieres el tamaño del puntero si no la **cantidad de elementos** de la formación, pero esa es una información que no tienes porque estás pidiendo memoria dinámica y ésta memoria carece de datos de ese tipo, puedes solucionarlo de las siguientes maneras:

1. **No uses memoria dinámica**:

   ```
   template <std::size_t tam>
   void a(const string (&as)[tam]) {
       for (const auto &s : as) {
           cout << s << endl;
       }
       cout << tam;
   }
   int main() {
       string as[3];
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           getline(cin, as[i]);
       }
       a(as);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. **Usa `std::vector`**:

   ```
   void a(const vector<string> &as) {
       for (const auto &s : as) {
           cout << s << endl;
       }
       cout << as.size();
   }
   int main() {
       vector<string> as;
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           string s;
           getline(cin, s);
           as.push_back(s);
       }
       a(as);
       return 0;
   }
   ```